# Clean URL from custom $_GET variables in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using wordpress pretty permalinks, my .htaccess file looks like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /nafham/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /nafham/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I'm using a form that displays the index page with url variables, like this:

```
http://www.nafham.com/?edu_year_selectionreal=79&semester_selectionreal=15&subject_selectionreal=80
```

I'd like to have the url to be displayed like this:

```
http://www.nafham.com/79/15/80
```

Is it possible to do so? and what's the best way of doing this in order not to make things go wrong with the rewrite conditions wordpress is Already applying?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as you have the rewrite already setup all you need to do is parse the url in your index.php

```
if (preg_match("#(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)#", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $regs)) {

    $edu_year_selection_real = $regs[1]
    $semester_selectionreal = $regs[2];
    $subject_selectionreal = $regs[3];
}
```

Comment: Sorry It requires 15 mins before accepting, and I had to go :D

Answer (score 0):

add smth. like this to .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^/([0-9-]+)/([0-9-]+)/([0-9-]+)$ index.php?var1=$1&var2=($2)&var3=($3) [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

At you need to set custom rewrite rules in the Wordpress otherwise Wordpress throw you to error page.

Here's example to set custom rewrite rules:

```
      <?php

  add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'insert_custom_rules');
  function insert_custom_rules($rules)
  {
$newrules = array();
$newrules['(.+?)/(.+?)/(.+?)/?$'] =
'index.php?edu_year_selectionreal=$matches[1]&semester_selectionreal=$matches[2]&subject_selectionreal=$matches[3]';
return $newrules + $rules;
  }
  ?>
```

Hope this will help.